# Center of SU(3)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, abelian-groups

I assumed a 3x3 matrix of the form  $$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
k & l & m
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then, since we know that the center is always an Abelian invariant subgroup and AB=BA, and the Gell-Mann matrices belong in SU(3), i took $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ which made the first matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & m
\end{pmatrix}$$
Knowing that $$det(A) =1$$ led to $$a^2m=1$$ And that's my question. Shouldn't i get numbers and not a and m for the center of the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center of $SU(3)$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_3$, generated by
$$
e^{2\pi i/3}I_3.
$$
You have written down elements of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, which are elements of a vector space.

Comment: I can know where i was wrong. But i can't prove it yet. I assume that we have to use $$e^{(ai{\pi} /n)} $$

Comment: There are several proofs given at this site (have a look), but they are of different levels. For example, check out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945453/which-generators-of-sun-generate-the-elements-of-its-center-zn), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718781/center-of-sun-group-in-general-young-tableaux-representation).